# How exactly are the three tamei klipot the source of a forbidden thing?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

I often hear that something which is forbidden originates from the three *tamei klipot* - where no good comes from - and as such it cannot be used for good. However, that which is permitted originates from *klipat nogah* and therefore can be used for good.

This would be clear to me if by something forbidden it meant something which is prohibited to the point that is even forbidden to benefit from it. However, if it is only forbidden for for some uses (i.e. having relations, eating, wearing, et al ...), but is permitted for other uses (e.g. a forbidden thing from which it is permitted to derive benefit), then how does such a thing originate from a place where there supposedly is no good (i.e. the three *tamei klipot*) if part of it either is good or can be used for good?

If the answer is that such a forbidden thing has sources in both types of *klipot*, then what is the source of this?

Comment: note that one of the example the Alter Rebbe brings in Tanya is Orlah. For the first 3 years the tree's fruits get their vitality from the 3 impure klippot. The same tree's fruits receive their vitality from Kilipot Nogah after that (except perhaps for Shevi'it)

Comment: The Tanya is the source for all of this. If it can't be found there, then there may not be an answer since the attribution of various objects in the universe to "klipot" - whether good or evil - is a circular and subjective activity (with the attributions you mentioned being specific to the system of the Tanya itself) and therefore often without basis in any source outside of itself. This should give the reader of the Tanya pause. Kol tuv.

Comment: @Maimonist I would not be surprised if this is found in earlier Kabbalistic works. Not that you agree with them either, but I don't see why it needs to be tagged Chabad

Comment: @maimonist I heard that the Tanya is called a collection of sayings, I do not think that the author wanted to trick you (call it a collection and write in it whatever he wants) at least most of it needs to be a collection (maybe part of it an explaination on how to understand the earlier sources)

Comment: @menachem by orlo I have no question it is forbidden for pleasure so it can not be used for good, but my question is by things that are permitted for pleasure but are forbidden for other things (I often here that chazer is an example of something that comes from the 3 tomai klipois)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Sichos Kodesh [Achron Shel Pesach 5736 number 10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4614&st=&pgnum=121&hilite=) and [Achrei 5736 number 5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4614&st=&pgnum=190&hilite=) from the Lubavticher Rebbe. In short summation, an object that is connected to the three *Klipot* but is permissible to derive benefit from means that the object itself can be elevated through those means, even though they derive from the three *Klipot*.

He [calls this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4614&st=&pgnum=130) (that there can be an elevation of the three *klipot*) a big Chiddush of the Alter Rebbe that no one comments on. Presumably, absent this Chiddush you would have to say that despite using them for permissible purposes, they are not elevated.

(BTW, as an aside, when it says they have "no good" it means they have no expression of good, as the life force that sustains them is totally submerged and does not express itself, not that it doesn't exist at all).